# Round number to nearest 000s in python

Tags: python

Rounded 0dp to nearest '000s, including its suffix (k/m/t). For example:

```
        6 --> 6
       23 --> 23
      465 --> 465
     3798 --> 4k
    43423 --> 43k
   910679 --> 911k
  8270192 --> 8m
 23890951 --> 24m
430493245 --> 430m
....
```

The numbers will be max `999,999,999,999`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your homework-solving community, you should provide the code you tried, issue you're facing, and ask for help on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numerize` for this. Documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/numerize/) -

```
#!pip install numerize
from numerize import numerize 

l = [6, 23, 465, 3798, 43423, 910679, 8270192, 23890951, 430493245, 999999999999]

for i in l:
    print(i,'->',numerize.numerize(i))
```

```
6 -> 6
23 -> 23
465 -> 465
3798 -> 3.8K
43423 -> 43.42K
910679 -> 910.68K
8270192 -> 8.27M
23890951 -> 23.89M
430493245 -> 430.49M
999999999999 -> 1000B
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the millify package at https://github.com/azaitsev/millify.  It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Are there any important differences between millify and numerize?